# JavaFX: can FXML field be private?

Tags: java, maven, javafx

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27884628/5057736) I see that a field is private. However, when I do

```
public MyController
{
    @FXML
    private Button button;
}
```

I get

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile
>   (default-compile) on project TEMP: Compilation failure
>   MyController.java:[x,x] button has private access in MyContoller
>   -> [Help 1]

Is this problem in maven or in javafx?

Comment: How about a problem in your code? How are you using `button`? Are you trying to reference it somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only say for sure that this is not a JavaFX problem not sure how you configured the compiler plugin but the problem must be there